# "Safe" File naming

Tags: windows, file, character, ascii, naming

Are there any "unsafe" file names that can be encountered in Windows, Mac OS, Linux, etc?

For example:

- `New Video 2012-External Room`
- `GED Practice Sheet`
- `RgRrE-re-_d Da-`

I've heard that even naming files with spaces, underscores, capital letters, and dashes could be potentially problematic, even though Windows doesn't include them in their list of forbidden characters. Is this true? I vaguely recall seeing programs that don't distinguish between uppercase and lowercase characters, and I know that HTML URLs encode unsafe ASCII characters as `%` (for example, spaces).

Comment: Are you only interested in "unsafe" names in Windows or in all the OSes you listed in the opening of your question? Different OSes have different rules about legal file names.

Comment: @rrufai all of the OS's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Unix-like (including Linux and Mac OS) and Windows should have no problem with underscores.  Spaces should also generally be fine, but you occasionally find buggy code that can't handle them.

For Windows, it's not that capitals are problematic.  It's that Windows filesystems are case-insensitive, so in some cases when interoperating (e.g. with a git repo which is case sensitive) you can end up with problems (e.g. the repo ends up with duplicates with different capitalization).

I'm not sure about `-`.  One reason to avoid it is that `-` has special meaning for many command-line programs (e.g. `rm -r`).  So you have to use annoying syntax like `.\-r`.  I would also generally avoid more exotic ones like %.

Answer (score 1):

It depends strongly on context of use. Certain non-forbidden characters can cause problems for certain programs, though the vast majority of applications which use standard system APIs should not encounter any issues.

Some programs (especially command-line tools) can be sensitive to the presence of spaces in the filename. Others may use only ASCII internally, and thus be incapable of handling filenames containing characters outside of basic ASCII. (Most modern OSes, by and large, will accept almost any Unicode character in a filename).

Some tools might require certain characters to be escaped (e.g. `%` in batch scripts), while others may not like having quotes in the filename.

Finally, a note on upper/lowercase: most Windows filesystems are case-preserving but otherwise case-insensitive, so upper/lowercase differences usually don't matter.

But, note that in almost every case, the files can still be used even if some workaround is needed to make them work.